# native query with spring data jpa doesn't return result

Tags: sql, spring, spring-data-jpa

Hello I have written the following method in spring data jpa repo:

```
@RestResource(exported = false)
@Query(
    value = "select q.* " +
            "from question q " +
            "left join question_program qp " +
            "on q.question_id = qp.question_id " +
            "where " +
            "q.difficulty_level_id = ?1 " +
            "and " +
            "q.paid = false " +
            "and " +
            "qp.program_id = ?2 " +
            "order by random() " +
            "limit ?3",
    nativeQuery = true
)
List<Question> getFreeRandomQuestions(
        @Param("df") Integer df,
        @Param("programId") Integer programId,
        @Param("qs") Integer qs);
```

It is returning an empty list whereas when I run the same query in pgadmin I get all the desired rows. It also works in spring data jpa if I remove the join with `question_program`. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

I have tried `select q ...` and `select * ...`. Both have the same problem

UPDATE:

I kind of solved this by implementing a service which fetches that data using sessionFactory and raw sql query!.

Comment: Should work ideally if the same query is working in pgadmin. Can you issue commit in pgadmin and retry?

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: I mean in the same pgadmin where you are running the query, you can write `commit` and execute it. Are you using any second level cache?

Comment: I do not understand why we need to commit in pgadmin. Query is already returning data in pgadmin. It is not returning in spring data jpa.

Comment: btw. i tried commit but no change

Comment: Because of transaction isolation, unless we issue a commit the changes will not be visible outside of that session. Sometimes we insert the data but forget to commit. Any second level cache you are using?

Comment: no second level cache.

Comment: Hmm...For me, commit and SLC are the prime suspects.. Hope you are connecting the correct DB/schema. Just to cross check you may want to try with other entities and see if you are able to read the correct data as in the DB.

Comment: it works if I remove the join with question_program. why is that?

Comment: But I thought you ran the same query (with same parameters) as it is in the pgadmin and able to get the results?

Comment: yes same query works in pg admin. 
But my above point was related to data jpa. In spring data jpa it works if I remove the join.